# sed delete lines before line beginning with pattern, do nothing if pattern not found

Tags: sed

I want to use sed to shorten a log containing lines which begin with a date:

```
2017-07-26T01:01:01 236
2017-07-27T01:02:01 236
2017-07-27T01:02:51 236
2017-07-27T01:03:01 236
2017-07-28T01:01:01 236
2017-09-07T09:05:18 236
2017-09-07T10:22:10 239
```

(no, logrotate won't do). I know that I can use

```
sed -i '0,/^2017-07-27/d' filename
```

to delete all lines (in place) before the first with '2017-07-27' on it and that first one, but if the file contains no such line, or only one such line, sed will delete everything. I'd like to do nothing if the pattern is not found.

I also want to delete in place.

How do I prevent sed from deleting all lines if the pattern never matches?
Is there a better way of doing this in place?

Comment: What output do you want ? Are you looking to obtain a list of dates ?

Comment: **NOT ckear enough**  So the first three lines should be removed?

Comment: records in log always comes in date order. You may check if date occurs and remove all records before `2017-07-27`

Comment: As stated in the explanation, the given command removes all lines before the one with the date, AND the first with the date. That's acceptable and in my case it doesn't matter whether all or only the first are removed.

Comment: To 'user' (first comment): no, I said I want to do nothing if there are no lines with the given pattern (date). The command listed will simply erase all lines if there is none with the given pattern.

Comment: OK, I figured it out myself: sed - a STEAM editor, so, if the pattern is not in the file, the editor will start with the first line, find no match and delete. This continues to the end of the file, as there will never be a match! Thus the answer: I can't prevent it using sed. Period!

Answer (score 0):

Never say never.

We can use the sed hold space to collect the desired output.  If we match the first line with the date, we throw away the accumulated contents of the hold space and start over with collecting the lines into the hold space.  At the end of the file, we print out the contents of the hold space.

The whole file will potentially end up in the hold space.  I suppose we could start printing each line directly instead of accumulating to the hold space once we find a match ... maybe.  But if there is no match, we still have to accumulate the whole file in the hold space - as potentially there will be a match on the last line and we'd have to throw out everything.  But I'm happy with this as it is.

I changed the example input slightly to make it easier for me to see which lines are which while developing the sed script.

```
bjb@rhino:~$ cat /tmp/sed.txt
2017-07-26T01:01:01 231
2017-07-27T01:02:01 232
2017-07-27T01:02:51 233
2017-07-27T01:03:01 234
2017-07-28T01:01:01 235
2017-09-07T09:05:18 236
2017-09-07T10:22:10 237

bjb@rhino:~$ sed -n ':begin H;/^2017-07-27/{s/^.*$//;x;s/^.*$//;n;b middle};$ b end;n;b begin;:middle H;$ b end;n;b middle;:end x;p;q' /tmp/sed.txt

2017-07-27T01:02:51 233
2017-07-27T01:03:01 234
2017-07-28T01:01:01 235
2017-09-07T09:05:18 236
2017-09-07T10:22:10 237

bjb@rhino:~$ sed -n ':begin H;/^fluffallaa/{s/^.*$//;x;s/^.*$//;n;b middle};$ b end;n;b begin;:middle H;$ b end;n;b middle;:end x;p;q' /tmp/sed.txt

2017-07-26T01:01:01 231
2017-07-27T01:02:01 232
2017-07-27T01:02:51 233
2017-07-27T01:03:01 234
2017-07-28T01:01:01 235
2017-09-07T09:05:18 236
2017-09-07T10:22:10 237

bjb@rhino:~$
```